# Golang and MongoDB - I try to update toggle boolean using golang to mongodb but got object instead

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I used to implement todo application using React and Nodejs. The toggle function in React and Nodejs to update Mongodb database as following code:

```
const toggleChecked = ({ _id, isChecked }) => {
  TasksCollection.update(_id, {
    $set: {
      isChecked: !isChecked
    }
  })
};
```

I would like to implement toggle function in Golang to update boolean field, but I got object instead, the following is golang code:

```
func updateOneMovie(movieId string) model.Netflix {
    id, _ := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(movieId)
    filter := bson.M{"_id": id}
    update := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"watched": bson.M{"$not": "$watched"}}}
    var updateResult model.Netflix

    result, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, update)

    err = collection.FindOne(context.Background(), filter).Decode(&updateResult)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(result)
    return updateResult
}
```

The result in Mongodb updates as the object instead of boolean. How can I fix to make it update toggle boolean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a single document (e.g. `bson.M` or `bson.D`) as the update document, field names and values will be interpreted as-is (literally).

To use [aggregation pipelines with updates](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), you must pass an array as the update document, this is what triggers interpreting it as an aggregation pipeline. This is the only requirement. The array may be [`mongo.Pipeline`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Pipeline), [`bson.A`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson#A), `[]bson.D`, `[]bson.M` or even `[]any`, it doesn't matter, it just must be an array or slice in Go. The elements may be `bson.M`, `bson.D` or any other values representing a document.

So the simplest solution:

```
filter := bson.M{"_id": id}
update := []any{
    bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"watched": bson.M{"$not": "$watched"}}}
}
```

Comment: like my solution is naive, your solution is the best! Thanks for your comment 

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I use Pipeline with bson.D as the following code:

```
func updateOneMovie(movieId string) model.Netflix {
    id, _ := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(movieId)
    filter := bson.M{"_id": id}
    update := bson.D{{Key: "$set", Value: bson.D{{Key: "watched", Value: bson.D{{Key: "$not", Value: "$watched"}}}}}}
    var updateResult model.Netflix

    result, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, mongo.Pipeline{update})

    err = collection.FindOne(context.Background(), filter).Decode(&updateResult)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Modified Count: ", result.ModifiedCount)
    return updateResult
}
```

The result, I can update boolean correctly.